# Django form creates default User rather than acustom User. How do I create a Custom User?

Tags: django, forms

Trying to extend Django's basic user model to a custom user model. I have a form for users to register, but when the form is sent it creates a default user, not a custom user.

I want it to create a custom user. The only way I seem to be able to create a custom user currently is through admin.

Here is my Django custom user model, which exists and can add users via admin.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(first_name, last_name, zipcode, email, username, password):
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name.")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name.")
        if not zipcode:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a zipcode.")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email.")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username.")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users mush have a password.")

        user=self.model(
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            zipcode = zipcode,
            email=email, 
            is_logged_in=is_logged_in, 
            is_bot=is_bot
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,
                    validators = [
                        RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
                                        message='Firstname must be alphanumeric or contain numbers',
                                        code='invalid_firstname'
                            )]
                )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,
                    validators = [
                        RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
                                        message='Lastname must be alphanumeric or contain numbers',
                                        code='invalid_lastname'
                            )]
                )
    zipcode = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="zipcode",
        validators=[RegexValidator(
            regex=r'^(^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$|^$)',
            message=(u'Must be valid zipcode in formats 12345 or 12345-1234'),
        )],
        )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250, 
        unique=True,
        verbose_name = 'email_address')
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 25,
                    validators = [
                        RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
                                        message='Username must be alphanumeric or contain numbers',
                                        code='invalid_username'
                            )],
                    unique=True
                )
    password = models.CharField(max_length =25,
        null=True)

    objects=MyUserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        #"Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        #"Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} ({self.last_name}) ({self.email})'
```

Here is my views file where I'm saving the form.

```
    #views.py
def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! Please proceed to agreements and payment.')
            return redirect('agreements_page')
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

### here is my form.py file

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    zipcode = forms.CharField(label='Zipcode', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    email = forms.CharField(label= 'Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'zipcode', 'username']

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.zipcode = self.cleaned_data['zipcode']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your app that your default user model is `CustomUser`. To do that, you need to add this to your `settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.CustomUser'
```

And in your view, you need to access your user such as:

```py
profile.user = request.user.get_profile()
```

This is also specified in a complete custom user example in the [official site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example):

> Finally, specify the custom model as the default user model for your project using the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting in your settings.py.

Comment: Thanks! Getting this weird error: AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'is_anonymous'. Any ideas?